# Using scroller in Hibernate throwing exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using org. Hibernate. ScrollableResults within the streaming mode.

I made sure that I won't have the n+1 problem. And put all joins in the same SQL statement.

For some reason in the while loop I am having an exception and before that I can see an additional select (beside the first select which we expecting while working in a Streaming mode)

Any idea what am I missing?

My scroller:

```
protected void scroll(ScrollableHandler<T> handler,String namedQuery, Object... values){
        T previousEntity=null;
        Session s = null;
        ScrollableResults results = null;
        try {
            s = (Session) em.getDelegate();
            org.hibernate.Query query = s.getNamedQuery(namedQuery);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
                query.setParameter(i, values[i]);
            results = query.setFetchSize(fetchSize).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
            while(results.next()) -> here I get the exception
                    {
                T entity = (T) results.get(0);
                if (null != entity && 
                        (! entity.equals(previousEntity))) {
                    handler.handle(entity);
                    previousEntity = entity;
                }
                s.clear();
            }
        } finally {
            if (results != null)
                results.close();
        }
    }
```

Logs:

```
11:54:24,182  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
11:54:24,182 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@729d8721 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
11:54:24,183  WARN CollectionLoadContext:347 - HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [3] entries
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not export
```

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used 2 queries. As we know we shouldn't open parallel query on an active streaming. Solution: avoid the second query.

ray.